# Is there a motive in favor of a 1 digit subnet in IPv4 space?

Tags: routes, ip-address, ipv4, notation

Had this discussion about network tables and databases with someone, and looking for more expert answers on this.
For the sake of argument, let's assume enormous amounts of routing, NAT and traffic shaping have to be done by a certain router;
This router needs to translate LAN to WAN IPv4 address space.

Does it make a difference if one would pick 192.168.**0**.1 over 192.168.**50**.1 for the processor in that router?
That router defaults with the .50 subnet, so one would assume that just considering workflow (after updates or resets) it would be smarter to use the .50 subnet, but what if there is A LOT of traffic within that address space over that router? Wouldn't the 1 digit subnet save space and time, and be more economic? Or is it processed (and cached/stored) as .000 and .050 anyway?
Of course, for a human typing the address, the 1 digit saves time, and the several tables and sheets with addresses in them would be smaller, but other than that, does the amount of digits in ipv4 addressing space count?

Answer (score -1):

Computers and routers work with bits, not their text representation. And IPv4 addresses are always 32 bits long. How we humans read and write numbers has nothing to do with how computers process them.

Comment: I realized that, but still it needs translation. It's about that translation stage where my question derives from. Lookups occur in the human readable form of the IP. Otherwise, why would the router store the IPv4 addresses non-binary in its config file and tables, and not use a 32 bit string?

Comment: Your assumptions are wrong. Routers use addresses in binary form. Config files and command line interface are just for humans.

Comment: My assumption is not wrong. If you're not able to read my replies, please stop repeating yourself.

Comment: Lookups do NOT occur in the human readable form. Go read https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

Comment: I don't think you really understood my question. It's about input of an IPv4 address, and what the hardware does with it, not the format it is in when the hardware has already translated the input address. Most routers I know hold the IPv4 address lists they keep on accessing not in binary form, but in human readable format. I used to code in assembly, and it would make a LOT of difference if there were extra digits before translation, especially when lists would be read a lot in a short time.